# What species is Nardole?

Tags: doctor-who

Several times in the latest season of *Doctor Who* the character Nardole has stated that he isn't human. Is there any information on what species he is?

I seem to remember that he might be some sort of cyborg but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

He is a humanoid cyborg.

In *Husbands of River Song (Christmas 2015)* he was decapitated by the body of King Hydroflax who used him to find River Song.

In *Extremis (S10E06)* we learn that following the last meeting of River Song and The Doctor on Darillium, The Doctor reassembled Nardole by glueing his head onto a body with an apparently cheap pair of lungs (as discovered in *The Pyramid at the End of the World (S10E07)* by a statement from The Doctor).

Comment: He also makes various statements about how his body parts are not all his. He hasn't seen his real face for a while, he won his left arm in a game, etc. Oh, and he was blue once.